# Not able to use escapeChar in hive as '\r\n"

Tags: hive

I am facing issue in Hive while defining the escape character in OpenCvSerde properties. As per the code below :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS databasename.tablename (
    ColumnName1 datatype,
    ColumnName2 datatype,
    ColumnName3 datatype
) ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = "|",
   "quoteChar"     = "\"",
   "escapeChar"    = "\r\n"
) Location '<HDFS LOCATION>' tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

The csv file is treating '\r\n' as same as '\n'. Which is making a difference in count of number of records.

Please suggest the solution so that I can use \r\n as escapeChar in OpenCSVserde properties, or there is any other possibility to make changes in serde properties. 
P.S Using org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde is mandatory for the purpose. 
I did go through link : [character slash is not being read by hive on using OpenCSVSerde](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979309/character-slash-is-not-being-read-by-hive-on-using-opencsvserde)

But it didn't serve my purpose.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

can you do an octaldump and see the delimiter?
Can you also specify the "escapeChar" as "\u001"
and try?

Comment: can you please try "escapeChar" = "\\"

Comment: Tried both "\u001" as well as "\001A". None of them worked. "\\" is not the requirement . Plus its not working too.