# HIVE - escape double quote issue

Tags: hadoop, hive, opencsv, hive-serde

I am trying to load a csv with pipe delimiter to an hive external table. The pipe occurring within data fields are enclosed within quotes. Double quotes occurring within data are escaped with \ . When I configure external table, I see data with double quotes are not interpreted properly.

> test.csv

```
id|name
105|"Test | pipe delim in field"
107|\" Test Escaped single double quote in HIVE
108|\" Test Escaped enclosed double quote in HIVE \"
109|\\" Test Escaped enclosed double quote in HIVE \"
110|\\" Test Escaped enclosed double quote in HIVE \\"
```

> External table create statement

```
drop table test_schema.hive_test;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test_schema.hive_test (id string, name string) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde' WITH SERDEPROPERTIES
(
"separatorChar" = "|",
"quoteChar" = "\"",
"escapeChar" = "\\"
)
LOCATION '/staging/test/hive'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

> Output

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| hive_test.id  |                 hive_test.name                  |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 105           | Test | pipe delim in field                      |
| 107           | NULL                                            |
| 108           | NULL                                            |
| 109           | NULL                                            |
| 110           | " Test Escaped enclosed double quote in HIVE \  |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

> Expected Output

```
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| hive_test.id  |       hive_test.name                            |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
| 105           | Test | pipe delim in field                      |
| 107           | " Test Escaped single double quote in HIVE      |
| 108           | " Test Escaped enclosed double quote in HIVE "  |
| 109           | NULL                                            |
| 110           | NULL                                            |
+---------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

Open CSV version 2.3

Comment: It seems to be a problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49979309/character-slash-is-not-being-read-by-hive-on-using-opencsvserde

Comment: I tried with additional lines 109 & 110 with double backslash as suggested in one of the solutions shared by you . I see 110 shows up value but again the second double quote is not showing up properly. Update the question with the tries

Answer (score 0):

Sadly it is not possible to achieve because OpenCSV use single character as escape and really you are trying to use double backslash as escape character (which would be a `string`). In the OpenCSVSerde class you can find that no matter what you pass as escape character,[OpenCSVSerde](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/OpenCSVSerde.java#L98) get the first character of your string value https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/master/serde/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/serde2/OpenCSVSerde.java#L98

Here is the current code as reference

```
  private char getProperty(final Properties tbl, final String property, final char def) {
final String val = tbl.getProperty(property);

if (val != null) {
  return val.charAt(0);
}

return def;
```

}

I think is missing a warning to let the user know at the moment of the table creation that only single characters are supported.